# Why does uniswap V2 re-read duplicate data? (Gas optimization)

Tags: solidity, uniswap, smart-contract

In the `transferFrom()` function, `msg.sender` is used to check the allowance and change it three times

Wouldn't it be better to set `msg.sender` once in a variable called `_msgSender` and then use `_msgSender` instead of repeating `msg.sender`?

```
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        if (allowance[from][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
            allowance[from][msg.sender] = allowance[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
        }
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
```

my suggestion :

```
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool) {
        address _msgSender = msg.sender;
        if (allowance[from][_msgSender] != uint(-1)) {
            allowance[from][_msgSender] = allowance[from][_msgSender].sub(value);
        }
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854256/how-much-accessing-msg-sender-costs-is-it-useful-to-store-it-in-a-variable-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CALLER operation which is reading the msg.sender global variable costs 2.

While MLOAD/MSTORE operations which are memory operations (storage where local variables are stored) costs 3.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854256/how-much-accessing-msg-sender-costs-is-it-useful-to-store-it-in-a-variable-and

thanks to [kfx](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/77075/kfx)